# Only if you come, will I go out

Tags: punctuation

Is a comma necessary in the above sentence?

My teacher was not able to explain why there should be a comma in this sentence whereas she asked me not to put a comma in this sentence-

Only if you are a member can you borrow books.

Could someone please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: A comma here is necessary because the sentence begins with a dependent clause

Answer (score 1):

Both sentence have the same syntactical construction. Therefore, it's a logical contradiction to claim that one *must* have a comma while also claiming that the other *must not*. So, based only on that, your teacher's claim is illogical.

---

> Only if you come, will I go out.

Is *only if you come* a dependent clause?

Consider this:

> Will I go out.

As a *statement*, this is not a proper sentence because it is not an independent clause (it does not stand on its own in a meaningful way).

Only if it were a *question* is it something that could stand on its own as an independent clause:

> Will I go out?

---

But you can't have a grammatical sentence that is formed *only* of dependent clauses. You can have a dependent clause, but only if there is also another portion of the sentence that is an independent clause.

As standalone fragments, both of these *could* be considered to be dependent clauses:

> only if you come
> will I go out

But if we stick them together into a single sentence, and we know that the sentence itself is grammatical, then we cannot separate one of the fragments from the rest.

As a result, the *entire* sentence must be a single, independent clause rather than either component being a dependent clause:

> Only if you come [,] will I go out.

No portion of this sentence is a dependent clause.

Given this, there is no dependent clause followed by an independent clause that would warrant a comma.

---

Nor is the comma being used in the formation of a series of list items or to set apart parenthetical information:

> ✔ Only if you come, bring me some money, and book us a reservation, will I go out.
> ✔ Only if you come, and come soon, will I go out.

---

In every way I look at it, the use of the comma in your first sentence is not something that should be used.

Therefore, I conclude this about the grammar of the various sentence forms:

> ✘ Only if you come, will I go out.
> ✘ Only if you are a member, can you borrow books.
>
> ✔ Only if you come will I go out.
> ✔ Only if you are a member can you borrow books.